How can I see the Python source code of a MacOS app created through Flet?
Is there any way I can see the source code of a MacOS app created through Flet? I just need to see the main Python code and was wondering if there's even a way to get to that.

I don't use Flet, but I looked at the documentation site and it seems like you write the code in Python yourself, it doesn't write it for you. https://flet.dev/docs/

Are you talking about the source code of the Flet library itself?

I think you can at least get the app code, although it might be compiled to Python bytecode. It’s not hard to reverse bytecode into usable source code (although it won’t exactly be the original code).

@nneonneo Thanks. Do you know how to do that? I looked at the documentation and couldn't figure it out.

It wouldn't be documented. It's probably in the app bundle under app.zip or something, but I'm guessing that from just reading the bundler code; I don't have an app handy to actually poke at.

If you mean is there a way to see the source code of the macOS bundle that has been built with flet build then no there is not as the code has been compiled and the Python runtime has been compiled in the executable
